# Verifying if an input is a username or email

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have one input which can be either username or email.  I can't seem to get this mysql query to work to automatically detect if it's a username or email and then return the id and apikey:

```
var sql = 'SELECT id, apikey from admin WHERE (username = ? OR email = ?) AND password = ?';
var sqlParams = [emailorusername, emailorusername, password];
mysql.query(sql, sqlParams, function(err,result){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        callback(err);
    } else{
        console.log('OK');
        if(result.length > 0){
            callback(null,result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What output do you get?

Comment: It prints 'OK', but result yield an empty array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using another strategy. Firstly, don't store the password as it is in the database. Store hashed value. Then search for the needed `user_id` and `password_hash` like this `select id,apikey,passoword_hash where user_name = ? or email =?`. After that, compare the hash with the hash from supplied password.